# What is the difference between conventional and unconventional path planning methods?

Tags: motion-planning, path-planning

Is there an exact definition for conventional and unconventional path planning methods? What are the features that help distinguish conventional and unconventional path planning methods? What is an example of conventional and unconventional path planning methods?

Answer (score 1):

Conventional methods relate to Djikstra algorithm, A-star algorithm or any other direct methods to find the path. Non conventional ones usually refer to genetic algorithms, particular swarm optimization, neural networks... Which are not thought for this geometrical issue, but for other kind of problems.